# Installing .EXE using WINE (OSX)

Tags: macos, installation, wine, program-files

I've used HomeBrew to install WINE on OSX.

I've downloaded the 64-bit .EXE from http://www.fastbem.com/Download.html

Now I try running it, which should install FastBEM into "Program Files"

```
piBookAir:Program Files pi$ wine ~/Downloads/FastBEM_Acoustics_Solver_Win64.exe 
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:mstask:MSTASK_ITaskScheduler_Delete 0x1531f0, L"Z  Users pi Downloads FastBEM_Acoustics_Solver_Win64.exe.job": stub
```

Now I'm not sure if this means it failed or it succeeded.  Looking in "Program Files" suggests it failed, because nothing is there, and it should be:

```
piBookAir:Program Files pi$ pwd
/Users/pi/.wine/drive_c/Program Files

piBookAir:Program Files pi$ ls -lat
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 pi  staff  170  4 Mar 23:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi  staff  102  4 Mar 23:19 Java
drwxr-xr-x  5 pi  staff  170  4 Mar 23:18 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi  staff  102  4 Mar 23:18 Common Files
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi  staff  102  4 Mar 23:18 Internet Explorer
```

I can't think of anything else to try. Is this a dead-end?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that WINE cannot run 64 bit binaries.

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.wine.devel/97417